Builder Tag in the content homepage item of my sitecore instance, why is it there?
On our Prod instance only on the Home page there is a Builder Tab, while on the Dev and other environments its not there? Also, all other pages on Prod do not have this.
I would like to remove this but cannot find any configuration to change this.
I've never seen this in any of my previous Sitecore installations.
Prod:

Dev:

Tried looking at condigurations, tried checking for any Ribbon code that could be doing this (there is no custom code to do something like this), tried checking Sitecore documentation for this behaviour.
